# How to dyanamically poppulate values to an extjs grid from servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, extjs

I have a servlet which returns an ArrayList to a Jsp .I have no idea on how to Add values from the Servlet to ExtJs dyanamically.

Comment: Use `JSON` `Array` for `ext js` .Which component you are using for loading the data in extjs ?

Comment: Hi, you should use any JSON library for return JSONArray from servlet. after that you can use this example for grid http://extjswithjava.blogspot.in/2013/12/hello-world-with-ext-js-mvc.html . In this example you can replace your sevlet URL.